# Python relative import causes syntaxerror: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path

I'm trying to install this great python module [Python-Chrono](http://oss.codepoet.no/python-chrono/wiki/Home) to my python environment, but it fails at least with python 2.4.3 and 2.6.6 with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "setup.py", line 30, in ?
    import chrono
  File "/home/janne/python-chrono-0.3.0/chrono/__init__.py", line 22
    from . import calendar
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The setup is using relative import mechanism and it should work just fine, but in my environment it causes this error.

Is there a way to get this fixed? Have you seen this kind of behaviour in your projects?

Answer (score 6):

Python 2.4 doesn't support that syntax - it was introduced in Python 2.5.

(Are you 100% sure that it's failing with that message in 2.6?)

Comment: Thanks for questioning my setup. It helped me solve the problem. :) I was playing with virtualenv at the same time and I guess that somehow messed up my python setup... now it works fine.

Comment: @RichieHindle I have a similar problem to the OP, could you comment on how I could replace the import line to make it work for python 2.4?

Comment: @mkm: Sorry, I don't know.